# Optionally match after a space

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that can match both of these lines:

```
foo/bar
foo/bar baz
```

And capture `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` into separate match groups.

I've tried with this regex:

```
^([^\/]+)\/([^\/#]+)? (\w+)$
```

Comment: @Tushar:  `^([^\/]+)\/([^\/#]+)? (\w+)$`

Comment: Check [`^(\w+)\/(\w+)\s*(\w+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/QoUYZB/1)

Comment: That did it, @Tushar ♥️.

Comment: What about this path `foo-bar/bar baz`?

Comment: @MaciejKozieja I've got that covered. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QoUYZB/3). Also, in the demo I've used `gm` flags since there are many lines of input to match from. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below regex

```
^(\w+)\/(\w+)\s*(\w+)?$
```

1. `^`: Starts with anchor
2. `(\w+)`: Match one or more word characters(alphabets, numbers and underscore) and add them to capturing group
3. `\/`: Match forward slash
4. `\s*`: Match any number of spaces
5. `(\w+)?`: Optional alphanumeric+underscore match
6. `$`: Ends with anchor

Here's [demo](https://regex101.com/r/QoUYZB/1) on RegEx101.com.

This will match first word before `/` in first capture group which can be accessed by `$1`, word after `/` in second group-`$2` and optional word in `$3`.

If there are other characters than `\w` i.e. `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, you can use below regex

```
^([^\/]+)\/(\S+)\s*(\S+)?$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QoUYZB/2)

`[^\/]+` will match one or more characters except `/`. `\S+` will match one or more non-space characters.

Comment: This is an ultra tiny point, but a more literal improvement for those who wonder about each component of a regular expression.  Please consider changing `\s*` to `\s?`. Searching for "0 to Infinity" spaces is unnecessary because there is never more than one space in the sample string provided.  `\s?` literally looks for 0 or 1 spaces.  I am sure you know this, but others who are new to regex may not and SO is wonderful educational resource.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this `^([^\/]+)\/([^\/#]+)\s*(\w*)$` with `g` and `m` flags.

Comment: Hm, that doesn't seem to pull `baz` into a match group in the line: `foo/bar baz`

Comment: You used `gm` flags?